Why don't jet fighters have fans?
Why don't jet fighters have fans in front? They only have a hole to suck air? I assume the compressor sucks the air. Is that enough?
See from picture below, this is an F-16 jet fighter. There is no fan. Only a hole under the cockpit to suck air. I just want to learn the reasons. Does the compressor suck air strongly?


The F-16 is powered by a General Electric F110 turbofan engine, which as the name suggests has a fan:

You cannot see the fan from the outside because the engine is located far behind the inlet below the fuselage. This image (from this answer) shows how air is directed from the inlet towards the fan:

Most (maybe all) modern fighter jets use turbofan engines (i.e. with a fan). However, turbojet engines without a fan were used on older fighters, e.g. the GE J79 used on the F-104. The compressor stages on these engines are sufficient to create airflow into the engine. The fan of a turbofan is not needed to direct air towards the engine. Its main purpose is to create accelerated bypass air, which does not go through the engine core.
There are also engines without any fans or compressors, like ramjets. However, these do not work from standstill and are therefore not practical for a fighter jet.

The F-16 has a lot of public attention, so you'll be able to (sometimes) find information via google searches. For instance, here's a video of an engine removal.

So is there an engineering reason for the extremely long intake duct on most fighters? Is it merely because they want to have the engine(s) close to the centerline but keep the intake as straight as possible? Or is there some reason that supersonic flight demands a long intake?
